# UILabel in UITableViewCell Getting Drawn Over Accidentally

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel

I'm using a prototype cell inside a grouped UITableView to create custom cells with two UILabels inside.  Each UILabel is populated with text.  The first UILabel, alligned on the left of the cell, behaves appropriately.

However, the second UILabel, which is toward the middle of the cell, is somehow being drawn behind the cell's background! I can't explain why, but if I set the background color of the cell to be clearColor instead of the default, the 2nd Label can be seen and works just fine.  It also shows up if I highlight the cell, but disappears again when unhighlighted.  I am sure that the label isn't just "blending in" with the background; the background is white and the label is black.

Any ideas?  I'm a bit stumped.  Is there some sort of issue with prototype cells and having more than one label?

Edit: Answered my own question, see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this has been resolved!

So like I said, I was setting up prototype cells in interface builder with two UILabels.  To access these UILabels in my cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate method for my UITableView, I was using the Label's Tags.  The first label I had tagged as "1", and the second label tagged as "3" (don't ask why it is 3 and not 2).  Anyway though, it turns out that UITableViewCells already have a label with special properties setup with tag 1.  Besides the label with tag 1 hiding my 2nd label, it was also remaining centered in the cell when I was changing cell size dynamically (when I wanted it to stay at the top).

Long story short: UITableViewCells have a "special" label already built in with tag of 1, so I changed my first label's tag to 10 and everything went back to behaving as I would expect.